# Multi-column webpage with individual scrollbars using CSS Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, frontend

I'm a new web developer looking to design a page similar to [this](https://fogstand.com/Contact) one as practice with columns in CSS. I'm currently unable to make each `<div>` in the flexbox container scroll individually.

[Link to current state (CodePen)](https://codepen.io/skro/pen/abJBdmZ)

I understand that `position: fixed` isn't compatible in a flexbox, but that's the only way I could think to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

https://codepen.io/Netswift/pen/ExWNPWy

`position: fixed` and `display: flex` work fine together - fixed positioning controls the position of the div relative to the , while flex display controls what's inside the div.

Comment: `<main>` now works like I'd like it to! I'm still also looking to give the furthest-right `<article>` element similar scrolling behavior. Appreciate you taking a look, would you have any tips for the `<article>` scroll?

Comment: Here you go @whole-earth - let me know if something doesn't make sense. https://codepen.io/Netswift/pen/ExWNPWy